# How to set the data of custom view in android activity.handle, and let its interface refresh the custom view's drawing?

Tags: android

As follow code show, in MyActivity.mHandler, the data from the peer Bluetooth is received (case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:),
Then I read and parse the data in MyActivity.mHandler and stuff it into ecgView (ecgView: is a custom View, used to draw electrocardiogram),
The problem now is that I adopt the following scheme, and the case Constants.MESSAGE_READ of mHandler.handleMessage receives the peer
After the data is collected, no matter whether the data source from the peer or the local hard-coded data source is inserted into ecgView,
the ECG line cannot be drawn (expected to be a red line graph on the grid)

ps: However, if the array content and setData operation are placed in MyActivity.onCreate(), they can be drawn successfully.

```
// It worked in below codes
MyActivity.onCreate(){
    dataSource = "[2081, 2083, 2085, 2086, 2086, 2087, 2089, 2092, 2095, 2097, 2099, 2103, 2052, 2054, 2056, 2057, 2058, 2057, 2056, 2054, 2052, 2050, 2048, 2047, 2045]";
    data_source = StringToAscii.test(dataSource);
    ecgView.setData(data_source);
}
```

Personally, I don’t understand what’s the difference. and code like mHandler: runOnUiThread(ecgView.setData(xxx)) doesn’t work, there is no drawing, and an error is reported(null point expception).

Excuse me, is there any good way here?

ps: I found that mConversationArrayAdapter.add of ListView is effective here. After adding, the data will be displayed in ListView in real time (MyActivity)

in MyActivity.java

```
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName + ":  " + readMessage);

                    //for ecgView data update
//                    Log.d(TAG, "mHandler - MESSAGE_READ: " + StringToAscii.parseHexStream(readMessage).toString());
//                  data_source.addAll(StringToAscii.parseHexStream(readMessage));

                    // local test data
                    dataSource = "[2081, 2083, 2085, 2086, 2086, 2087, 2089, 2092, 2095, 2097, 2099, 2103, 2052, 2054, 2056, 2057, 2058, 2057, 2056, 2054, 2052, 2050, 2048, 2047, 2045]";
                    data_source = StringToAscii.test(dataSource);  // use the local test data, but can't show the ecg chart
                    Log.d(TAG, "cmm - data_source = " + data_source.toString());
                    if (null != data_source && data_source.size() > 0) {
                        ecgView.setData(data_source); // set ecgView chart data source
                        //ecgView.requestLayout();
                        //ecgView.invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
```

in EcgView.java:

```
    private Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas();

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mCanvas = canvas;
        DrawECGWave(canvas);
    }


    /**
     * Draw Ecg Chart
     */
    private void DrawECGWave(Canvas canvas) {
        ...
    }


    /**
     * set data source for ecgChart point
     */
    public void setData(ArrayList<String> data) {
        this.data_source = data;
//        DrawECGWave(mCanvas); // doesn't work
        invalidate();
    }
```

ps: However, if the array content and setData operation are placed in MyActivity.onCreate(), they can be drawn successfully.
// It worked in below codes
MyActivity.onCreate(){
dataSource = "[2081, 2083, 2085, 2086, 2086, 2087, 2089, 2092, 2095, 2097, 2099, 2103, 2052, 2054, 2056, 2057, 2058, 2057, 2056, 2054, 2052, 2050, 2048, 2047, 2045]";
data_source = StringToAscii.test(dataSource);
ecgView.setData(data_source);
}

Personally, I don’t understand what’s the difference. and code like mHandler: runOnUiThread(ecgView.setData(xxx)) doesn’t work, there is no drawing, and an error is reported(null point expception).

Excuse me, is there any good way here?

ps: I found that mConversationArrayAdapter.add of ListView is effective here. After adding, the data will be displayed in ListView in real time (MyActivity)